# Cannot Change Brightness of "HP g6 - 1d26dx"

Tags: laptop, hp-pavilion

I formatted my notebook yesterday and installed the drivers from [the official site](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=5228839&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5186811&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4063#93211).  However, I cannot change screen brightness.  This is a drain on my eyes and my laptop battery.  Help!

Comment: Have you tried pressing the F2 key, or Fn and F2 together? Are you sure you have installed all the drivers, and in the right order? What OS are you using - presumably it's Windows 7? You need to provide more information.

Comment: I would also add that normally on a laptop it is possible to manually adjust screen brightness via the Control Panel: http://www.whatthetech.com/2010/11/22/how-to-adjust-power-settings-in-windows-7/

Comment: @James : yeah i have installed win 7, but in control panel the power option is also not available i cannot change via control panel. Please Help ....